# Parse SDK - similarTo type of query

Tags: parse-platform, similarity

I have an app in iOS and android and I'm getting the user's location in both of them! With CoreLocation for iOS and Google Maps in android... After the location retrieval, we apply reverse geocoding, to get the locality out of them... Once we do, we perform equalTo queries to find photos of a specific location...

The thing is, there are occasions where the locality of iOS, is slightly different to android's! For example, "Palaiochori" in iOS and "Paleochori" in android! Observe that two letters are different!

So, whereas the location is the same in both devices, the equalTo query will obviously fail!

What I want to know, is if there is any way to create a type of query, where we don't check for equality. Instead, we check for similarity!

Notice, that we do use cloud code, so any server-side solution is acceptable and preferred!!

Comment: I know nothing about app development so only a comment, but to me it seems that the problem is not with the comparison, but with the reverse geocoding. You say "**we** apply reverse geocoding", so does your geode source have tow different Palaiochori geovalues?

Comment: @Toby We're using 2 different location SDKs for each OS, Apple's and Google's, so I guess it's logical to have some differences... Note that using only one, is not an option!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the location name can not guarantee uniqueness. Two possible solutions:

1. Ensure consistency of your database

Store a `GeoPoint` for these locations. When you already have `Palaiochori` in your database and a user finds himself in `Paleochori`, *before saving a new object*, run a `whereNear()` query to see if you have near places for that location.

If you have results within a reasonable radius, ask the user: Do you mean `<list of near places>`? The user will likely recognize the place with a similar name, and tap on it. This way you avoid duplication.

2. Use a consistent location database

As soon as you have `lat/lng`, you could use **Google Places API** to ask for places near that location. Google will return a `Place` object with a unique `placeId` that you can store in your database. The id is guaranteed to remain the same and can be used for your queries reliably.